# Link dropdown menus populated by mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

Excuse me if i've got the terms wrong as i'm new to development, but I have a multiple dropdown menu's linked so that the results from the the previous menu determine what the next menu will populate the next.

i.e. if i select uk, the next list will show, London, If i select Spain, the next list will show Madrid

My dropdown menus are getting populated by mysql, this is fine but how do i link them up without calling on another page

**Here's an example of what HTML i have:**

```
<div id="container">
  <h3>Price List</h3>
  <form method="post" action="" name="form1">
  <? 
  include 'classes.php';
  $query="SELECT * FROM Sex_Table";
  $result=mysql_query($query);
  ?>
  <div id="select-1">
    <select class="calculate" name="sdf" onChange="getClothing(this.value)">
    <option value="0">Please Select</option>
    <? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <option value=<?=$row['Price']?> sex_price="<?=$row['Price']?>"><?=$row['Sex_Name']?>&nbsp;(£<?=$row['Price']?>)</option>
  <? } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
  <? 
  $Sex=intval($_GET['Sex_var']);
  include 'classes.php';
  $query="SELECT * FROM Clothing_Table WHERE Sex_Table_ID='$Sex'";
  $result=mysql_query($query);
  ?>
  <div id="select-2">
    <select class="calculate" name="sdf" onChange="">
    <option value="0">Please Select</option>
    <? while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <option value=<?=$row['Price']?> sex_price="<?=$row['Price']?>"><?=$row['Clothing_Name']?>&nbsp;(£<?=$row['Price']?>)</option>
  <? } ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

You'll notice that on change calls on "getClothing(this.value)"

Here is that js:

```
function getClothing(Sex_Table_ID) {        

    $.ajax({
       type: "get",
       url: "findClothing.php",
       data: { Sex_var: Sex_Table_ID },
       error: function(error) { alert('System error, please try again.'); },
       success: function(data){ //data is the response from the called file
         $("#select-2").html(data); //this changes the contents of the div to data that was returned
       }
     });    
}
```

I need it so that it doesn't call on url: "findClothing.php", as once it does this, my price no longer calculates.

I'm sure i don't really need to show this part but just incase, here's what calculates my price:

```
$(function(){
    $('.calculate').change(function() {
        var total = 0;
        $('.calculate').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() != 0) {
                total += parseFloat($(this).val());
            }
        });
        $('#total').text('£' + total.toFixed(2));
    });

});//]]>
```

Comment: consider including `'classes.php'` only once at the beginning of your script. reading a file before performing each query puts unnecessary load in your server and (depending on what you do in that file) may be unnecessarily opening new connections to the mysql server

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your ajax data contains option tag with price as a value?

Also change:

```
$('.calculate').change(function() {
```

with

```
$(".calculate").live("change", function(){
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers if you are using higher jquery version.